# Android: How to record on top of a music being played?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I am researching for this question for the past week but still no answer. Below is what I am trying to do.

1. Play a background music inside the app. Maybe by using `MediaPlayer`
2. While the music is being played, allow the user to record his voice inside the app- like in Karoke, you may use `MediaRecorder` to record
3. Attach the music and recorded vocal as a one file, now when you play this what you hear is music+voice.

I went through several Stack Overflow answers and even payable and free libraries for audio editing, no good result yet. But I know these are possible because it is happening in this app, even in a "much" advanced level - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smule.singandroid

Note, I am an experienced software engineer. So sometimes before doing something I can say whether what I am going to do is working or not. I know how to play a music, then record a sound, but I don't know how to make it as one, where the both being played in parallel. So there is no use of showing how I "play the music" using `MediaPlayer` and how I record my voice using `MediaRecorder`, it is simply going to waste the time of other experienced people around here trying to observe the code.

Comment: I never worked with this kind of thing, but I think if you have any means of getting an array of samples (bytes or short ints) from your audio streams, you can mix them by just adding them up, or calculating an average to avoid clipping. Then, just convert your new array of samples back to an audio stream. However, this is only possible if both audio streams have the same sampling frequency.

Comment: @Milack: wow, OK, sounds too complex for me (seems like sound engineer required!!)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I didn't mean to scare you, haha.. Actually, it's not that complex.  An audio stream is nothing more than an array of samples, which are integer numbers (say 16 bits each, or short ints). A stream has a sampling frequency, which tells us what is the time period between two consecutive samples in that array. If both your music and voice streams have the same sampling frequency, you can sweep their arrays and produce a new one: `mix[i] = (music[i] + voice[i]) / 2`. Then, just convert the mix array back to an audio stream.

Comment: Of course, you can do all this stuff if you don't find any other "higher level" way. Ideally, the Android system should provide an API to mix multiple audio streams, no matter their sample size, sampling frequency, etc. If not, maybe you can find a third-party library capable of doing it.

Comment: This article seems to be very useful: http://mobilengineering.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/audio-mix-and-record-in-android.html
It seems that Android itself doesn't have a built-in API to mix audio streams, so you need to do it yourself. If you can set the audio format of the recorded voice stream to be exactly the same of the music, it will be easier to mix them.

Comment: Hey @YohanWeerasinghe were you able to find any solution. I am also stuck at the same place and I have not been able to find any good solution as of now.